# displaying help messages while docker build

Tags: docker, docker-build

I am building a Dockerfile and I would like to display some help messages while building it.

I also tried `RUN echo "installing this"` but as expected, it doesn't work.

So, How do I display help messages and if possible while running the `docker build` command in quiet mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A priori `RUN echo "installing this"` should work and display something. However it would be somewhat bad practice to have a `RUN` layer with only a single echo command.

Indeed as mentioned in the page [dev-best-practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/dev-best-practices/):

> If you need to use a version of Docker that does not include
>   multistage builds, try to reduce the number of layers in your image by
>   minimizing the number of separate `RUN` commands in your Dockerfile. You
>   can do this by consolidating multiple commands into a single `RUN` line
>   and using your shell’s mechanisms to combine them together.

For additional, related recommendations, there is also a page [dockerfile_best-practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/).

For the use case you mention in your question, you could either write

```
RUN echo "install this" && command that install this...
```

or maybe just

```
RUN set -x && command that install this...
```

to automatically display the command that is run during the `docker build`.

But if you use the `docker build --quiet` option, I am unsure it is possible to achieve what you want.

So if you really want to have some concise/quiet build log while displaying specific info messages, you could try removing `docker build`'s `--quiet` option but combine `set -x` with redirections such as `command that install this >/dev/null`.

Comment: Thanks! even though I am not able to remove the messages that `docker build` shows, using `set -x`, highlights my commands ( in red. I don't know if it will be same for all systems), so this solutions works!

Comment: @scipsycho I'm glad that the proposed solution works for you. Regarding the red color that you get: it is not specific to `set -x` but to the default printing of standard error messages by `docker build`. As a result, you will also get some red output if you compile a `Dockerfile` with `RUN echo error >&2`.

Comment: As an aside, assuming `set -x` is set, the prompt before the name of each executed command is defined by the special variable [PS4](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-PS4) that can be customized if need be.

Comment: Thank you for telling me about `PS4`. Learned something new!

Answer (score 37):

I had a similar problem with docker build where `RUN echo` commands were not showing . I was able to fix it by modifying the build command to

`docker build -t hello-world ./ --progress=plain --no-cache`

The important thing here is the `--progress=plain` option as docker defaults to `auto` and hides too much output. The `--no-cache` option is necessary to rebuild the container to show all of the output.

Comment: do you mean to say the echo commands *weren't* showing until you set --progress to plain? I'm guessing that other people have tried to correct your answer as well. Stackoverflow says there are too many pending edits. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: yes, that's correct @mihow. Thanks for catching that typo